# regex for trimming letter/word if preceded by 2 white spaces

Tags: php, regex

Could you please help with `preg_replace` regex for trimming letter/words if appears after 2 or more white spaces? i.e.:

```
lorem ipsum  x
```

to become

```
lorem ipsum
```

also would be great to left trim if word/letter followed by 2 white spaces i.e.

```
x  lorem ipsum
```

Comment: A letter in Unicode regexes (regices, rēgēs :) is `\pL`, and white space is `\s`. What else do you need to know?

Comment: For your last example would you want it to match the `x  ` or the `lorem`?

Comment: I would like to match/remove x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should match 2 or more whitespaces, followed by any number of consecutive "word" characters

```
$rx = "/\s{2,}\w*/";
```

Comment: great stuff, that I understand :-)

Comment: Watch out, this one will match two line breaks or tabs followed by a word!

Comment: @hughes -- yep you're right.  I assumed we were going line by line. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex that will match the criteria you described (note the leading spaces may be hard to see):

```
  \w+?\b
```

Demo: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2ucpq

Edit: looks like to make this actually work in PHP, you need leading and trailing slashes:

```
preg_replace('/  \w+?\b/','','testing pro  x');
```

Comment: thanks, but how to use it? `preg_replace('/\w+?\b/','','testing pro  x');` seems to not working

Comment: I should imagine that `/\h{2}\pL+/` is all you want.

Comment: btw what the \h{2} and \pL means ?

Comment: @Marcin, it didn't work for you because you dropped the leading spaces. I've added a usage example to my post.